# Create custom PhoneNumber Token Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

in ASP.NET Identity 2,PhoneNumber Token is 6 digit by default.
i want to override `GenerateAsync` and and make it 4 digit,
`GenerateAsync` signature is `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` and dont accept my `ApplicationUserManager`

how can i create custom PhoneNumberTokenProvider??